# How to validate a sale with PayPal REST API and IPN

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal, paypal-ipn

I currently have a fully working cart and checkout process through PayPal _xcart method, but I want to migrate it to REST API, mainly because I want to mitigate the possibility of price-jacking. Currently my IPN does check for price jack and sets the according flags so the product doesn't get downloaded (selling digital products only). Anyway more to the point, I found the PayPal documentation very confusing and I'm struggling to get the full grips of it.

This is what I have understood and worked out till now.

1. Using my PHP script (let's call it page A) I create the cart content, then I create a new PayPal sale and redirect the client to PayPal for authentication
2. Client authentication on PayPal, then it's redirected back to my site to page B (page B is defined in page A)
3. Page B needs to get the PaymentID (from page A) and use it to effectively complete the transaction. Once competed finalize the checkout.

Now here are my problems:

a) I had read quite a few forums and tutorials and they all mention that I should use a session to store the PaymentId from Page A and then use it in Page B to finalize the transaction. Some threads on SO suggests that PayPal should actually include the PaymentID in the call to page B, along with the token and the PayerID. Those are almost 3 years old posts and during my testing I see that PayPal now does return the PaymentID as well.

- <strike>Is this a new thing, did PayPal really started to send the PaymentID as a GET variable?</strike> OK I found this on PayPal SDK documentation (not PHP of course some other language) that they return the PaymentID as well as a GET.
- <strike>Is there any disadvantage on using the GET presented by PayPal compared to storing a session from page A to B? I don't really wan't sessions, so GET will be ideal for me.</strike> I guess if it is on PayPal documentation it's safe to use.
- <strike>Will this work on the live page as well or only in Sandbox?</strike>

b) On Page B when I execute the Payment I get a nice JSON as response, but in the same time my IPN listener also gets called, and this is what confuses me big time. Can/Should I just trust all the data which is in the JSON response and more or less ignore the IPN listener? This will make sense for instant download, for example, much more easier to process, or should I still rely on the IPN for data validation?

- If I use only the JSON returned to Page B, which are the correct fields to look for and what values? For example, there is a state field which is approved and another (Transactions -> related items -> state) which is competed. Which one do I need to check?
- If I rely on the JSON do I still need to check if the paid amount matches the original amount or can I trust that the payment is equal to the amount I have requested in my call?
- If I use the IPN how can I pare it with the transaction? The PaymentID doesn't show up in the variables posted to the IPN. The only way I could think of is to get  the txn_id from the JSON response, but somehow that feels odd, plus how can I know if the JSON response hit the server BEFORE the IPN?

Comment: So you're basically saying "please don't link me to the answer to my question."  ;)

Comment: You can put it that way too, unless that links pointing to somewhere were things are written down black on white (can be able on white as well for PayPal official colors) but the instructions and the reference should be clearly understandable...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can/Should I just trust all the data which is in the JSON response and more or less ignore the IPN listener?

Yes, and no. In that order.

In a nutshell, you can't trust the payment ID in the call to "Page B" (it could be forged, faked, repeated etc) but you can trust the response YourServer->PayPalServer as it can't be intercepted and faked by the end user.

**So your process is** (as you describe above)

1. Page A: Create a sessionID (cookie), amount, cart details etc and store in a local database/storage. You can also create a "custom" field to store your own saleID
2. Send off amount etc to Paypal, which returns you to ....
3. Page B: Grab the PayPal TransactionID and send back (server->server) to PayPal. Paypal returns the amount, state etc. Then check your database that the amount is the same and that it belongs to the sessionID. If you also use custom fields, check that too. If everything marries, you're good. If not, it's up to you how to handle.

The status should be "complete" for a simple sale at this point; but (as with IPN below) you should verify this.

Do check the amounts, just in case. They should match, but if not, the PayPal one will be what you receive and it's up to you to accept it, flag it (and phone up) or refund through the API and reject the order etc.

**So why have IPN?**

It is possible that the user completes the transaction on Paypal and then closes their browser before "Page B" is called. In this case, the only way you know about the order is through the IPN.

If you get an IPN notification going to your IPN handler, IPN can still be faked, but there's a slightly different way of verifying.

You actually send the IPN information back to Paypal (server to server) and Paypal confirms it's correct or wrong (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/). Your IPN handler will then check the transaction ID (yes, that's what you use) and verify everything matches in the database (just like you do in "Page B"). If it does, mark the order as complete if the status is complete (and if not already marked as complete in "Page B").

Obviously you can't display anything to the user at this point as they are not the ones that called the page.

The docs above warns you that you can get multiple IPNs for the same transaction so you also need to check status.

(Note: you could use the APIs to verify the transactionID as you do in "Page B").

**So why not reply on IPN?**

Paypal warn that the IPN may not arrive. Paypal explains it best:

> Although PayPal usually processes IPN messages immediately, IPN is not synchronized with actions on your website. Internet connectivity is not always 100% reliable and IPN messages can be lost or delayed. The IPN service automatically resends messages until the listener acknowledges them. The service resends messages for up to 4 days.
>
> Because IPN is not a real-time service, your checkout flow should not wait for the IPN message before it is allowed to complete. If the checkout flow is dependent on receiving an IPN message, processing can be delayed by system load or other reasons. You should configure your checkout flow to handle a possible delay.

**So back to the original question**

Yes: rely on the JSON (server->server) call you make to verify the parameters to "Page B" (and in and the IPN handler if you choose)

No: Don't ignore the IPN in case Page B never gets called. But still run the verification checks here too.

Yes: Check state = complete for both "Page B" and "IPN handler"

Yes: Use the Paypal TransactionID, but mix into your own database with either custom fields or sessionID.

Yes, you can/will get both Page B and IPN notifications, I'd suggest ignoring the IPN if the payment is already marked as completed, otherwise process and handle appropriately. They should be using the same database.

Comment: Thank you. Nice and clear explanation (in plain english) which makes things clear. Can I ask for a small top up, if you know. If the API response is pending instead of completed (eCheque, possible fraud, etc), I guess I will have to wait for an IPN notification (at a later stage) which will complete/deny/cancel that payment, right?

Comment: That is correct. Just display "Awaiting clear funds - we will email you when your order is complete", update your database (so you can follow up at a later date) and await the IPN. If IPN never comes through, you might want to run a manual check periodically as PayPal want the IPNs might fail. (I've never actually had a pending, though, or different amounts, but do code for it.)

Comment: This answer is incorrect regarding the use of IPN. The IPN cannot help if the redirection after approval fails, because the authorized payment will not be executed and the IPN will not be sent. It is only sent after the payment is executed. I cannot see any use for the IPN in the new REST workflow. The REST workflow has indeed the weakness that it relies on a redirection  and thus on the client's browser to pass the approval. They removed the 10 seconds delay on the Paypal page, but still the browser can be closed before the redirection is received. The IPN cannot help.

Comment: Can you clarify which bit of the answer is incorrect? The answer does not refer to what happens if the payment does not go through - as you indicated If the authorized payments doesn't happen then you won't get an IPN. But you don't need (or want) an IPN in this case. As explained in the answer you should (but not guaranteed) get an IPN for a completed payment and you can use as a second level back-up if the flow through the browser is not completed - that's where it fits into the workflow. It's not required, but it's a safety net.

Comment: Thanks for excellent answer.  IPN includes txn_id which corresponds to CaptureID obtained from REST API.  However to get information on a transaction, the Order ID is needed, which is not included in the IPN.  How inconvenient!